# How to create a product layer using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement an SPN (http://spn.cs.washington.edu/pubs.shtml) using tensorflow.
In an SPN, we only have sum or product nodes. A value of a sum node is computed by summing the product of its respective edge-weight and corresponding child. A value of a product node is the product of its children.

This is a toy example:
[image]

I could easily compute the first sum layer using this piece of tensorflow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.set_random_seed(0)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 6])
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([6, 4]))
S = tf.matmul(X,W)


sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
r = sess.run(S, feed_dict={X: np.ones([1,6])})
print(r)
```

Which gives me the correct values for the sum nodes in the first layer:

```
[[ 6.  6.  6.  6.]]
```

My question is how can I compute the product layer?

The product node should create the following output:

```
[[36. 36.]]
```

I tried to use [**tf.reduce_prod**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/reduction), but it only gives [[1296.0]].

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: `[tf.reduce_prod(a[:2]), tf.reduce_prod([2:])]`

Comment: Thank you, @YaroslavBulatov. I am wondering if there is a way of automating this layer. Something similar to determining the filter size in a CNN. For example, suppose I want to multiply the nodes 3 by 3 and not 2 by 2 as in my toy example. Instead of creating arrays and repeatedly call *reduce_prod*, do you know if there is a tf function to do the equivalent? Thx.

Comment: I would use a Python for loop for this

Comment: Sounds like efficient enough :)  Thank you again